# Can I use tor.exe for my stuff?

Tags: proxy, terminal, tor-network

As you may know, programs like Tor Browser come with a tor.exe program.

I'm not an expert, but I would say the executable is responsible for sending and receieving information by the Tor fabric.

Does it work as a standalone program? Can I use the executable via the terminal to send my own stuff through it (as  proxy or with a concrete input from the terminal for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can! Tor.exe is a standalone daemon that can perfectly fit even a case when it is executed as as system service! Just put it all on the right place - and enjoy! If you'll describe your particular case - I think I'll be able to help you better - so just expand your question!

Comment: First of all, thank you for such a kind answer! I know this question might be boring or pointless, but to me it matters a lot!

Second, I don't have a concrete case, but let's say I wanna do some connections to an IP using my own Python script and this executable. How would I use the Tor fabric? By sending the request to the executable as if it was a proxy, by telling the program to do the request via some commands...?

Comment: Exactly - Tor is a Socks5 and HTTPS CONNECT proxy, so it's control interface is a telnet-based one. So you use Stem library for the control protocol and just any library you wish to use for a proxified connections. Nothing more! And you better take a tor.exe from an expert bundle - it's *just* it without a browser or anything else